# Replacing keys of an associative array with values of a different associative array with same keys

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an associative array as given below:

```
$baseArray = array(
    'a' => array('apple', 'mango'),
    'b' => array('lettuce', 'spinach'),
    'c' => array('carrots', 'radish'),
    'd' => array('beans', 'okra'),
    'e' => array('chicken', 'mutton')
);
```

I have another associative array with same keys as below:

```
$arrayWithRequiredKeys = array(
    'a' => 'Fruits',
    'b' => 'Leaves',
    'c' => 'Roots',
    'd' => 'Veggies',
    'e' => 'Meat'
);
```

I need the keys of `$baseArray` to be replaced by the values from the respective keys of `$arrayWithRequiredKeys` such that the output array is as follows:

```
$desiredOutput = array(
    'Fruits'    => array('apple', 'mango'),
    'Leaves'    => array('lettuce', 'spinach'),
    'Roots'     => array('carrots', 'radish'),
    'Veggies'   => array('beans', 'okra'),
    'Meat'      => array('chicken', 'mutton')
);
```

Is there any php inbuilt function to perform the above job? Or do I have to create a customised function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Comment: Note that `array_combine` doesn't match the keys as such, it just takes the order they are in the arrays.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, I just faced that while trying to use array_combine().

Comment: If `array_combine()` is not suitable then your [mcve] is an inadequate representation of your task/data.

Comment: @mickmackusa my question is not about why array_combine() does not work.

Comment: Cool, then the duplicate is correctly applied.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a simple foreach loop in combination with `try/catch`:

```
<?php
$baseArray = array(
    'a' => array('apple', 'mango'),
    'b' => array('lettuce', 'spinach'),
    'c' => array('carrots', 'radish'),
    'd' => array('beans', 'okra'),
    'e' => array('chicken', 'mutton')
);

$arrayWithRequiredKeys = array(
    'a' => 'Fruits',
    'b' => 'Leaves',
    'c' => 'Roots',
    'd' => 'Veggies',
    'e' => 'Meat'
);

$desiredOutput = [];

foreach ($arrayWithRequiredKeys as $key => $value) {
    try {
        $desiredOutput[$value] = $baseArray[$key];
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "No such key: $key";
    }
}

print_r($desiredOutput);
?>
```

This yields

```
Array
(
    [Fruits] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => mango
        )

    [Leaves] => Array
        (
            [0] => lettuce
            [1] => spinach
        )

    [Roots] => Array
        (
            [0] => carrots
            [1] => radish
        )

    [Veggies] => Array
        (
            [0] => beans
            [1] => okra
        )

    [Meat] => Array
        (
            [0] => chicken
            [1] => mutton
        )

)
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/q14vGx).

Comment: I have tried something similar (without the try/catch). Was wondering if php provides any inbuilt method for this job, array_combine() does not exactly do what I want though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple foreach if you know exist like:

```
$newarray = [];
$baseArray = array(
    'a' => array('apple', 'mango'),
    'b' => array('lettuce', 'spinach'),
    'c' => array('carrots', 'radish'),
    'd' => array('beans', 'okra'),
    'e' => array('chicken', 'mutton')
);

$arrayWithRequiredKeys = array(
    'a' => 'Fruits',
    'b' => 'Leaves',
    'c' => 'Roots',
    'd' => 'Veggies',
    'e' => 'Meat'
);

foreach($baseArray as $key => $value){  
        $newarray[$arrayWithRequiredKeys[$key]] = $value;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newarray);
echo '<pre>';

/*
Array
(
    [Fruits] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => mango
        )

    [Leaves] => Array
        (
            [0] => lettuce
            [1] => spinach
        )

    [Roots] => Array
        (
            [0] => carrots
            [1] => radish
        )

    [Veggies] => Array
        (
            [0] => beans
            [1] => okra
        )

    [Meat] => Array
        (
            [0] => chicken
            [1] => mutton
        )

)
*/
```

You can use [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) like.

```
$newarray = array_combine($arrayWithRequiredKeys, $baseArray);
```

**Warning : Returns the combined array, false if the number of elements for each array isn't equal.**

Comment: I have tried something similar. Was wondering if php provides any inbuilt method for this job. Someone suggested array_combine(), but it does not exactly do what I want.

Comment: For real if you use $newarray = array_combine($arrayWithRequiredKeys, $baseArray); like this without my foreach the result is same